# How to pass more than one argument in component function in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

How to pass more than one argument in components function in React

```
 function Ads(product_title, description) {
    return(
      <div className = "row" id="user-ads">
     <div className = "col-sm-6 col-md-5">
      <div className = "thumbnail">
      <img src = "img/img1.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div className = "caption">
      <div className="border">
         <h3>{product_title.title}</h3>
         <p>{description.desc}</p>  
            <button className = "btn btn-primary" role = "button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">View Details
            </button>  
              </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                    </div>
      );
```

}

```
ReactDOM.render(<Ads title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum"/>, document.getElementById('ads'));
```

The code above only takes the value of first parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless React components only receive a single argument, an object that contains all the props:

```
function Ads(props) {
  // access props.title
  //        props.desc

  // ...
}
```

Maybe that becomes more obvious if you [look at what the JSX is actually converted to](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3CAds%20title%3D%22PlayStation%204%22%20desc%3D%22Lorem%20ipsum%20jipsum%20Lorem%20ipsum%20jipsum%22%2F%3E&playground=true):

```
// Before:
<Ads title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum"/>
// After:
React.createElement(
  Ads,
  { title: "PlayStation 4", desc: "Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum" }
);
```

---

A common pattern is to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) to get direct access to the props:

```
function Ads({title, desc}) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: TypeError: product_title is undefined

Comment: You have to use `props.title` **instead of** `product_title` everywhere. I thought that would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, `product_title.desc` should have the value you're looking for. When you're calling `<Ads title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum"/>`, both `title` and `desc` will be passed to your component function as properties of an object, so both will be available in your function with the name of the first param you specified, which in your case is `product_title`.